# Bootstrap 4 dropdown button doesn't drop

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, dropdown

Seems like a simple problem, it's likely I'm missing something obvious.

I have a card layout with a series of text / buttons / lists inside. One of these buttons is a dropdown, and for some reason the dropdown doesn't "drop". This code is copied directly from [bootstrap 4's site on dropdown menu buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/), except for the button class styling (outline-primary).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: The markup is fine: https://www.codeply.com/go/A0QeXvRECX .. make sure bootstrap.js, jquery and popper.js are correctly referenced and check the browser console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `Bootstrap JS`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
         <button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
          </div>
```

Refer this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't used anything that required the script as well until now.

Answer (score 0):

Are all your js files included? Jquery, Popper and Bootstrap?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```